# AWS Billing Service not included in Golang AWS SDK

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I see that the AWS Billing service was not included into the Golang SDK

We need to make a Lambda to connect with this service and collect the monthly billing to make a dashboard.

How can we do that ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The go sdk's [cost explorer package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/costexplorer) gives access to the [aws cost explorer api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Types_AWS_Cost_Explorer_Service.html):

> You can use the Cost Explorer API to programmatically query your cost and usage data